# How do I shorten multiple LIKEs

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

My query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE (
  col LIKE '%this%' AND 
  col LIKE '%that%' AND 
  col LIKE '%something else%'
)
```

The strings I'm searching for are NOT in a predictable order.

Is there a way to write this without all those `LIKE` lines?

Comment: if the words appear in a specific/consistent order, then you can try `%this%that%something else%`, otherwise: no, you couldn't shorten that, other than switching to a fulltext index allowing you skip the wildcard business. `%..%` are absolute crap for search performance - you can't use indexes and each query has to do a full table scan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
WHERE col LIKE '%this%' AND col LIKE '%that%' AND col like '%something else%'
```

you may try this for faster way:

```
WHERE col REGEXP 'this|that|somethingelse'
```

but be aware that this is only applicable if there is a specific pattern else I dont think that it can be shortened.

**EDIT:-**

As your updated question says if the strings which you are searching are not in a predictable order then I dont think that there is any way to shorten your LIKE statements. You have to use it in the same way in which you are using it right now.

Comment: Hm, too bad there's no way to shorten the statement, but at least now I know.

Comment: OP wants records matching all 3 like statements. Using `this|that|somethingelse` you get rows matching at least one of them.